# read csv file with com.opencsv.CSVReader in java using 10 threads

Tags: java, multithreading, opencsv

I have a `sample.csv` file which has 10000 rows. I want to create 10 threads like 1st thread should read first 1000 rows , second thread should read from 1001 to 2000, 3rd thread should read from 2001 to 3000 ..... 10th thread should read from 9001 to 10000. How can I achieve this scenario in Java

Comment: Unless every row has exactly the same length, there is no way to do this, since there is no way to seek to row 1001.  Also, parallel reading of a single file usually doesn’t provide a noticeable gain in performance.

Comment: Every row has same length

Comment: You should start by writing a separate method that reads lines 1–1000.  Then, add an int parameter to the method containing the line at which to start reading.  Finally, you can create threads (or pass tasks to an ExecutorService) which each call that method with different values.